# How does iTunes block my non-Apple device?

Tags: curl, authorization, httprequest, itunes, user-agent

I'm trying to load the following resource from a non-Apple device:

http://a1285.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Music/e2/62/81/mzm.fiyyuoea.aac.p.m4a

The URL was served by the iTunes Search API. It plays fine from an iPhone browser but my Linux Chrome browser gets a 403 Forbidden response.

I tried to spoof the User-Agent header with Curl:

`curl -v -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16' http://a1285.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Music/e2/62/81/mzm.fiyyuoea.aac.p.m4a`

But I still get 403 Forbidden. This file plays just fine from an iPhone browser. How does Apple know to block my device without looking at the User-Agent header?

**Edit:**

Here's the curl output from a machine that can load the resource:

```
curl -vI http://a1285.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Music/e2/62/81/mzm.fiyyuoea.aac.p.m4a
* About to connect() to a1285.phobos.apple.com port 80 (#0)
* Trying 23.67.251.59... connected
* Connected to a1285.phobos.apple.com (23.67.251.59) port 80 (#0)
> HEAD /us/r30/Music/e2/62/81/mzm.fiyyuoea.aac.p.m4a HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.4 (universal-apple-darwin11.0) libcurl/7.21.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
> Host: a1285.phobos.apple.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache
Server: Apache
< Last-Modified: Wed, 12 Sep 2012 07:32:54 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 12 Sep 2012 07:32:54 GMT
< ETag: "ff7b1-4c97c32e92716"
ETag: "ff7b1-4c97c32e92716"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 1046449
Content-Length: 1046449
< X-Server: nk11p00it-web038
X-Server: nk11p00it-web038
< Date: Sun, 21 Jul 2013 07:50:18 GMT
Date: Sun, 21 Jul 2013 07:50:18 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Type: audio/mp4
Content-Type: audio/mp4
< 
* Connection #0 to host a1285.phobos.apple.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Here's the curl output from my machine which cannot load the resouce:

```
curl -vI http://a1285.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Music/e2/62/81/mzm.fiyyuoea.aac.p.m4a
* About to connect() to a1285.phobos.apple.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 124.40.233.83...
* connected
* Connected to a1285.phobos.apple.com (124.40.233.83) port 80 (#0)
> HEAD /us/r30/Music/e2/62/81/mzm.fiyyuoea.aac.p.m4a HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.27.0
> Host: a1285.phobos.apple.com
> Accept: */*
> 
* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Server: AkamaiGHost
Server: AkamaiGHost
< Mime-Version: 1.0
Mime-Version: 1.0
< Content-Length: 359
Content-Length: 359
< Expires: Sun, 21 Jul 2013 07:56:14 GMT
Expires: Sun, 21 Jul 2013 07:56:14 GMT
< Date: Sun, 21 Jul 2013 07:56:14 GMT
Date: Sun, 21 Jul 2013 07:56:14 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Type: audio/mp4
Content-Type: audio/mp4

< 
* Connection #0 to host a1285.phobos.apple.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe apple scans what operating system the host is running, and if it sees Linux then it discriminates accordingly.  You may want to perform a test using a WINE supported version of Firefox and running Windows XP's version of Firefox.exe under WINE and see what you get this time.  If it doesn't ban you under the WINE interface, it would mean that apple is seeing that you are running WINDOWS and if that is the case, I would perform more hacks on the native chrome browser to see if it goes thru this time just fine.  I know that there is many Firefox plugins that may help you out, however, you will need to download the linux version of Firefox before you can try these plugins and extensions.

Comment: How can it scan my operating system? I'm simply sending an HTTP request to a remote server. Does that information get sent with my request?